# AjaxControlToolkit error: tsm combinedscripts=true

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been receiving an error from an application in regards to toolscriptmanager. Please see the exception below:

```
Error Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Inner Exception: 

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.OutputCombinedScriptFile(HttpContextBase context)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what this could be? I have been referencing [this](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/15245) ticket, but cannot seem to replicate the error.

Comment: Im havin the same issue, but in my case I some how get & instead of & in the url, and im using the latest version of ajax control toolkit.